# Как правильно использовать laravel-echo-server для cross domain?

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-echo

Есть backend на laravel (**api.domain.local**) и frontend (**localhost:3000**) на react
Laravel выступает в роли api.

Между собой общаются без проблем, есть необходимость пристроить broadcast от laravel
я выбрал redis + socket.io, взял готовый пакет laravel-echo-server

Конфигурация echo server такая:

```
{
  "authHost": "http://api.domain.local",
  "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
  "clients": [],
  "database": "redis",
  "databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
      "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
  },
  "devMode": true,
  "host": null,
  "port": "6001",
  "protocol": "http",
  "socketio": {},
  "sslCertPath": "",
  "sslKeyPath": "",
  "sslCertChainPath": "",
  "sslPassphrase": "",
  "subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
  },
  "apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:3000",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
  }
}
```

На стороне фронта так вызываю Echo:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import env from '../env/env';
import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  crossDomain: true,
});

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

const EchoServer = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});

export default EchoServer;
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MUVFI1G' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Много комбинаций laravel-echo-server.json перепробывал, ничего не помогает, помогите плз!

Answer (score 0):

```
new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
    auth: {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  });
```

**transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']**
Но щас Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 419 но думаю это уже решится)